# HttpListener writing data to response output stream

Tags: c#, streaming, httplistener

I have small local web server based on HttpListener. The server provides files to local client application unpacking and writing files to

```
response.OutputStream;
```

but sometimes files (videos) are huge and I don't think it's a good idea to always copy all file bytes to output stream (memory). I would like to connect served file stream to response output stream something like this:

```
response.OutputStream = myFileStream;
```

but -ok- `response.OutputStream` is read only so I just can write bytes - is there any way to make some kind of partial writing (streaming)?

Regards.

Comment: so... you are trying to create a streaming connection, next step will be to divide the file to seperate packages and send them all simultaneously and reconstruct them at the client-side... why won't you just do that?

Comment: Served video files are displayed in web browser (gecko fx) and when video (mp4) request comes (html5 <video> tag) - the request do not specify requested bytes range (for buffering for example) so I don't know how to realize the partial sending.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a thread and stream your data to response.
Use something like this:

in your main thread:

```
while (Listening)
{
    // wait for next incoming request
    var result = listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

somewhere in your class:

```
public static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var listenerClosure = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
    var contextClosure = listenerClosure.EndGetContext(result);

    // do not process request on the dispatcher thread, schedule it on ThreadPool
    // otherwise you will prevent other incoming requests from being dispatched
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        ctx =>
        {
            var response = (HttpListenerResponse)ctx;

            using (var stream = ... )
            {
                stream.CopyTo(response.ResponseStream);
            }

            response.Close();
        }, contextClosure.Response);
}
```

Comment: Here's a similar post (has more context): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385633/serving-large-files-with-c-sharp-httplistener?rq=1

Comment: I think that stream.CopyTo(response.ResponseStream) copy all file bytes to output stream and this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: UGEEN, if you set .AllowWriteStreamBuffering property to false, it will not cache anything locally. It will stop sending when client stops receiving.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have HttpListener in my case and HttpListenerResponse. I would like to stream video file data to WebBrowser video tag (html5) - is there any way to set AllowWriteStreamBuffering in this case - I didn't found the way and after hours of seraching give up:-)

Comment: Ouch.. that property is on the Request, client-side. I somehow assumed that you were streaming data to server, e.g. uploading it.

Comment: Well, normally if you don't want to send everything from server, you need to expect client to tell you what exactly it needs. For video, there may be special conventions - but for regular data, clients usually attach 'content-range' header in which you can expect to receive the range of bytes that client wants to get in response to this particular request. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716680/difference-between-content-range-and-range-headers

Comment: Also, keep in mind that even though CopyTo will send everything, it won't attempt to cache that data in server memory first. HttpListener's response implementation also does not cache sent data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers - it helps to understand the nature of the problem.