# ASP MVC 4 in Windows Service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-services

I am currently building a Windows Service.
It does its job, so that it not the problem.

To do some monitoring and to be able to do some configuring of the Windows Service, I want to embed a web administration tool, hosted in the Windows Service itself. Just like the ones we know from our routers, network printers etc...

I already found out that I can self host an ASP WebApi in my Windows Service, but that means I still need to have an external webpage that connects to the API. I'd rather have the Windows Service hosting an ASP MVC website to be able to benefit from all its capabilities (I want to embed CSS, Javascript libraries and use SignalR)

Anyone has any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852859/call-subroutines-via-url-across-local-network ?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385633/serving-large-files-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Answer (score 3):

have you tried the servicestack approach? they use a windows servcice as a host, [in this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService) they implement a mvc/service solution