# How to use BackgroundWorker in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

i'm new to winform and i can't figure out how to use the BackgroundWorker.

basically what i'm trying to do is this:

i have 1 form with 2 buttons: "Import" and "Exit" . when calling ImporButton_Click all it does is creates an HttpListener and listen to a given URL. ExitButton_Click closes the form.

the problem is when i press "Import" the form get stuck and it's in "not responding" status until someone is calling the listener and free it.

i'm trying to under stand how BackgroundWorker can help me to overcome that "stuck" problem. i don't understand how to invoke the backgroundWorker1_DoWork method

Here is my code so far:

```
//Program.cs 
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ConfigurationForm());
    }
}

//ConfigurationForm.cs
public partial class ConfigurationForm : Form
{
    public ConfigurationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UrlTextBox.Text = @"enter URL here";
    }

    private void ImporButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String urlToListen = UrlTextBox.Text;

            //Invoke MyListener 
            MyListener.StartListen(urlToListen); //assume this is implemented
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            string errorMsg = String.Format("An exception occured = {0}", exception);
            MessageBox.Show(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

so, what now ? how do i invoke the backgroundWorker1_DoWork ???

10x to anyone who can help

Comment: You don't show the code where your real problem lies leaving as *"assume this is implemented"* :) For example , see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385633/serving-large-files-with-c-sharp-httplistener)

Comment: well , this is exactly my point. i don't know where to call the backgroundWorker1 from.

Comment: You need a tutorial; there are already many on the web, try [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this method [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync.aspx)

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

If you want to pass some `argument` into the handler `DoWork` via the `DoWorkEventArgs`, try the second overload of `RunWorkerAsync`:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(yourArgument);
```

Comment: But where do i call it from ? from the ImporButton_Click() method ? should my MyListener.StartListen(urlToListen) logic be inside the RunWorkerAsync() ?

Comment: @Dardar it depends on what you want your `BackgroundWorker` to do. Right after calling the method, your `BackgroundWorker` will do the thing you want in the `DoWork` event handler.